# TFS - Query to find list all epics containing work items in my current sprint

Tags: tfs, agile

I have a list of user stories in my current sprint and I'm trying to get an organized list of all the associated epics for those items.

Some of these are directly parented by epics and some of them are grandparented.  In both cases, I'd like to end up with just the list of epics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to query the epics directly which containing work items in the specific sprint if you didn't set the iteration path for the epics.

You can use the query type : `Work items and direct links` or `Tree of work items` to get the epics list if you have already set the iteration path for the epics. Reference below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That worked, except I had to remove the Iteration Path criteria from the parent query, since the epics themselves in this case aren't set to the current iteration.  The query result will list all of the epics, but only expand to work items for the current sprint.  Thanks.